# The association X refers to the inverse side field Y which is not defined as association

Tags: php, symfony, associations, field

I have two entities:

`Team`:

```
class Teams
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="team")
     *
     */
    private $id;
```

`User`:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $team;
```

**One** team have **many** users

And I've got these errors:

> The association App\Entity\User#team refers to the inverse side field
>   App\Entity\Teams#id which is not defined as association.
>
> The association App\Entity\User#team refers to the inverse side field
>   App\Entity\Teams#id which does not exist.

I don't know where I'm wrong... Anyone know ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm bit confused of what you want to do.

If you want unidirectional relation from user side then remove

```
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="team")
```

this code.

And user should have only

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Teams")
 */
private $teams;
```

On the other hand if you want bidirectional relation then add property user on teams entity.

It doesn't work for you because the mapping you defined is on $id and it should be on the property

**Bidirectional way:**

```
class Teams
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="teams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
```

---

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Teams", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $teams;
```

It's good practice to name entities with singular name so perhaps you'd like to change Teams to Team entity.

Check also http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

Answer (score 0):

You want your Team to look like this:

```
class Team
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
    private $users;
```

This will generate teams of users.  If you want your users to be able to on more than one team change your User call to a ManyToMany as well.

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Team")
     */
    private $teams;
```